# pyspark how to pass the values dynamically to countDistinct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file that contains (FileName,ColumnName,Rule and RuleDetails) as headers.

[image: InputFile]

I have multiple rules for column Rule like NotNull,Max,Min etc.
For the rule "Unique" there can be multiple columns, I need to pass those columns and perform countDistinct.

[image: Code]

If I pass the values dynamically instead of hardcoding I'm getting below error

[image: ErrorMessage]

```
AnalysisException: Column '`"SITEID", "ASSETNUM"`' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.ASSETNUM, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.HasLD, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.SITEID, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.Status, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.SerialNumber, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.Description, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.InstallDate, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.Classification, spark_catalog.maximo_dq.Assets_new.LongDescription];
```

2. Similarly how to get the count of records which are not matching the specified date format.
   [image: Input which has Rules]

I need to take check how many records in INSTALLDATE are not in the format of RuleDetails

Comment: Please don't post images of codes, and always provide reproducible example so people can debug

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tuple unpacking`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpacking-tuple/) to pass the values

```
UNIQUUECOLSString = ['a','b','c'] #keep it in an array
df.select(countDistinct( *UNIQUUECOLSString ))
```